# как в ангуляр директиве сделать проверку на наличие класса

Tags: angular, angular-directive

у меня есть директива в которой я к элементу при клике добавляю класс selected и также при повторном клике убираю класс.

```
@HostBinding('class.selected') isSelect = false
@HostListener('click')
  toggleAddClass() {
this.isSelect = !this.isSelect
}
```

Но я хочу чтобы у меня класс selected добавлялся только к одному элементу, и при клике на другой элемент, класс из старого удалялся, и добавлялся к новому
Сейчас это выглядит так

[image: пример изображения]

код из html

```
<div
  #leftChild
  class="left"
  [hidden]="dateLoaded">
  <button
    select //директива которая додает класс
    [disabled]="disabledForLeft"
    *ngFor="let left of left"
    class="left__data"
    (click)="kim(left)">
    {{left?.coin_name}}
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Картинку лучше бы заменить текстом.

Comment: Здесь картинка показывает что происходит при клике т.е на каждый элемент при клике добавляется класс, а нужно чтобы класс добавлялся только к одному элементу

Comment: Принципиально ли тут использовать директиву? Можно список выводить через *ngFor, и через переменную index проверить, что выделенный элемент соответствует текущему и назначить на него класс через ngClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Директива для таких целей не подходит. Директива может взаимодействовать только с тем компонентом, на котором объявлена. Вы же хотите задействовать общение между директивами, для этого потребуется добавить какой-то сервис общения.

Для упрощения конструкции стоит обратить внимание на `*ngFor`, а также сопоставление активного элемента и индекса в массиве.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  activeIndex = 0;
  array = ['coin1', 'coin2', 'coin3', 'coin4', 'coin5', 'coin6'];
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of array; index as index;" [ngClass]="{selected: index === activeIndex}" (click)="activeIndex = index">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

Пример на https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2hunas